# Returning the entire dataset using Google App Engine indexed search

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there any way to fetch the entire dataset in an app engine search index? The below search takes an integer limit through `QueryOptions`, and the limit which always needs to be present.

I'm unable to determine if there is some special flag that can bypass this limit and return the entire result set. If the query is made without a `QueryOptions`, the result set is limited to 20 somehow.

```
_INDEX = search.Index(name=constants.SEARCH_INDEX)
_INDEX.search(query=search.Query(
  query,
  options=search.QueryOptions(
      limit=limit,
      sort_options=search.SortOptions(...))))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could customise the delete all example, if indeed you want every document in the index rather then every result in a query https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Python_Deleting_documents_from_an_index

```
from google.appengine.api import search

def delete_all_in_index(index_name):
    """Delete all the docs in the given index."""
    doc_index = search.Index(name=index_name)

    # looping because get_range by default returns up to 100 documents at a time
    while True:
        # Get a list of documents populating only the doc_id field and extract the ids.
        document_ids = [document.doc_id
                        for document in doc_index.get_range(ids_only=True)]
        if not document_ids:
            break
        # Delete the documents for the given ids from the Index.
        doc_index.delete(document_ids)
```

So you might end up with something like:

```
while True:
    document_ids = [document.doc_id
                    for document in doc_index.get_range(ids_only=True)]
    if not document_ids:
        break
    # Get then something with the document
    for id in document_ids:
        document = index.get(id)
```

You'd probably want to get the document itself in the list comprehension rather then getting the ID then getting the document from that ID, but you get the idea.

Comment: Sweet.. will try this. How well do you think this technique will scale if the number of results go into tens of thousands?

Comment: depends on how quickly you need the results re-generated I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you peek into the constructor of QueryOptions, that answers your question why it returns 20 results:

```
def __init__(self, limit=20, number_found_accuracy=None, cursor=None,
               offset=None, sort_options=None, returned_fields=None,
               ids_only=False, snippeted_fields=None,
               returned_expressions=None):
```

The reason I think why the API is doing this is to avoid unnecessary fetching of results. You should use an offset if you need to fetch more results upon user action instead of always fetching all results. See [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/queryoptionsclass).

```
from google.appengine.api import search
...
# get the first set of results
page_size = 10
results = index.search(search.Query(query_string='some stuff',
    options=search.QueryOptions(limit=page_size))

# calculate pages
pages = results.found_count / page_size

# user chooses page and hence an offset into results
next_page = ith * page_size

# get the search results for that page
results = index.search(search.Query(query_string='some stuff',
    options=search.QueryOptions(limit=page_size, offset=next_page))
```

Comment: Yes i read about this, but i need all the results for kind of a backend stats page. No pagination is required.

Comment: I am not quite following what you trying to do on your backend stats page. Maybe if you describe your use case that will help. My guess is maybe you could put some huge number for limit . After all, if you have a datastore that is full of things that will match a search query. I would question how useful the data is or the search query.

Comment: What i need is to basically dump the search results on a simple html page.. i think if nothing works pagination can be looked into. The thing is though, currently, the same stats page fetches the document list from an NDB. But the datastore doesn't have any property for some new info required on the stats page. The search index by design however fetches this extra data along with the document information. This makes the result lookup rather convenient. Otherwise i'll have to look through another table or two to get the same data and somehow join them.

Comment: @abhink did you figure out how to force fetch all results or did you use the paging anyway? I'm having a simular use case where I need all the results.

Comment: @StephanCelis We had to resort to paging. Although to generate the required view, we just fetched every entity from the relevant datastore model. The data was not indexed but still completely present. I remember resorting to tasklets to manage that.